# > Task :react-native-android-location-enabler:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED - how to solve this error?

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, npm, compiler-errors

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-android-location-enabler:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.gradle.internal.compiler.java.ClassNameCollector (in unnamed module @0x725819c8) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$TypeSymbol (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.code to unnamed module @0x725819c8

**my project react native version "react-native": "0.63.4",**